# Not showing my reference link

Tags: php, sql

```
function select_History_Date($link){
    $status = '';
    $sql = "SELECT Student_Id, Loaner_Laptop_Id, HDD_Id, "
        . "Phone_Id, date_returned " 
        . "FROM equipment_history WHERE Loaner_Laptop_Id "
        . "IS NOT NULL OR HDD_Id IS NOT NULL OR Phone_Id IS NOT NULL";
   $ret = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
   $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC);    
     if (!$ret) {
      die('Could not execute select statement:' . mysqli_errno($link));
     } else {
     while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     $status .= '<tr>';
     if(is_Null($row1)){
        $status .= '<td><a href="ReturnLaptop.php?laptopId=' . 
                 $row1['Loaner_Laptops_Id'] . 'studentId='. 
                 $row1['Student_Id']. '">'. 'Return'. '</td>';
         } else{
        $status .= '<td>' . $row1['date_returned'] . '</td>';
        }            
        }
        $status .= '</tr>';
        return $status;
 }
}
```

With How I envision it this should be printing the href link but its just printing blanks Am I missing something? Or is this simply just not possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `$row1` is `null`, but it can never be `null`, since you are assigning it in a `while`. If you are in the `while`, it already means it's not `null`.

My bet it that you miss an index to your `if(is_null($row1))`, like `if(is_null($row1['value_to_check']))` for example.

Comment: My thought was $row1 is similar to an element in an array. It changes every time does it not?

Comment: $row1 IS the array, not an element of it. Plus, while statement loops as long as its condition is true. If $row1 is null, then it's false, and it won't loop anymore. $row1 can never be null in your loop. One of its array index could be, on the other hand.

Comment: So change it to be something like  if (is_null($row1['date_returned'])){

Comment: Yes, I guess, depends on the data you don't want to be null, but seeing your else statement, i'd say that's what you want to achieve yes.

Comment: I noticed that and it worked how I wanted thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You get from db `Loaner_Laptop_Id`

```
$sql = "SELECT Student_Id, Loaner_Laptop_Id, HDD_Id, "
        . "Phone_Id, date_returned " 
        . "FROM equipment_history WHERE Loaner_Laptop_Id "
        . "IS NOT NULL OR HDD_Id IS NOT NULL OR Phone_Id IS NOT NULL";
```

than use  $row1['Loaner_Laptop`s`_Id'] check key :)

Comment: Thank you I just noticed that. Sadly it didn't fix it